# Magento2 : Product urls not generating

Tags: magento2, seo

I have a site with multiple websites in a single magento instance.Each website has a different root catalog.

"Use Category Path for product urls" is enabled and I am trying to generate product urls using this https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl and Mirasvit SEO Module.

But Not all products are getting SEO Urls Some Product urls are generating like the below: https://new.dcsgrills.com/catalog/product/view/id/20547/s/dcs-30-inch-traditional-built-in-grill-non-rotisserie-bgc-model/category/1743/

Can any one please guide me on this

Comment: Did you fully reindex?

Comment: Yes Reindex is Done

Comment: write a shell php  and load all products to a collection then inside that  product looop call product save()

Comment: I tried by saving manually the above product from admin.But still url keys are not generated

Answer (score 0):

Your rel="alternate" meta tags are wrong. Please use the following instead;

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://mystore.com/us/men/shirt/polo-red.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://mystore.com/uk/men/shirt/polo-red.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-fr" href="http://mystore.com/fr/men/shirt/polo-red.html" />
```

SUGGESTION: You will need to use some extension or hard code to automatically generate it for all product pages. But it should be like the above sample.

Hope it helps.
Good Luck!